# Nginx - ip to https

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx configuration issue.
I can't force the use of HTTPS when access services via @ip:port in the browser.
For example, i use emby and emby.domain.com redirects to https://emby.domain.com.
But myip:8096 (emby port) doesnt redirect to https://...
And it's the same for all services.
Surprisingly, if i only enter the server's ip without port, it redirects me to https://myip and i get 404 error.

Here's my server blocks :

```
ssl_certificate /crt/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /crt/ssl.key;

# redirect 80 to 443
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# stop main domain access
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        ssl on;

        location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

# a service for example
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my.domain.com www.my.domain.com;
        ssl on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
}
```

Have you and idea ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `default_server` in your HTTP block `listen_directive`, so that it looks like this:

```
# redirect 80 to 443
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This causes nginx to send all requests to this `server` block that neither have a `Host` header or requests that contain a `Host` header that doesn't match any configured `server_name` for the port.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I added default_server directive but i still cant join web services via https://myip.

Comment: Misread your question. All your services must perform the rewrite themselves, unless you are using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of them.

Comment: I have 2 services Emby & Deluge (ports 8096 & 8112) which are reachable via the nginx reverse proxy at adresses emby.domain.com & deluge.domain.com. The only thing that worries me is that these services are not reachables via "https:// 1.2.3.4:8112" & "https:// 1.2.3.4:8096" while there is no problem to reach them by http. Dont see what i miss in Nginx configuration ...

Comment: The reason is that those services themselves listen to those ports on the IP address. That is bad configuration, you should make sure that the applications bind themself to localhost only, and that you configure firewall properly so that only access to nginx is available from outside. You want a single access method to your services, and that is via nginx reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your confing is wrong, it should be like this

```
ssl_certificate /crt/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /crt/ssl.key;

# redirect 80 to 443
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# stop main domain access
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        ssl on;

        location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

# a service for example
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my.domain.com www.my.domain.com;
        ssl on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://yourip:8096;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i corrected that but i still cant get https by entering @ip.